# Excel VBA Page break on change in cell

Tags: excel, vba

I have a list which I've ordered by "author".  I am trying to write code to insert page breaks, so that I can print out a list for each author.

Here's the code I've written, which goes through and selects the correct cell where I want a page break, but for some reason it just doesn't insert the break.  I'm not getting any errors, it just doesn't insert the break.

```
Sub addpagebreaksatvalue()
    Dim x As Integer
    Dim LR As Integer
    Dim Fname As String

    LR = Cells(rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    Fname = Cells(2, 5)

        For x = 3 To LR
            If Cells(x, 5) <> Fname Then
               ActiveWindow.View = xlPageBreakPreview
               Cells(x, 1).Select
               ActiveWindow.SelectedSheets.HPageBreaks.Add before:=ActiveCell.Offset(0, 0)
               Fname = Cells(x, 5)
               Else: Fname = Cells(x, 5)
            End If
        Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Has done some small changes to your code see comments within it:

```
Sub addpagebreaksatvalue()
Dim x As Long
Dim LR As Long
Dim Fname As String

    'Need to declare the object to work with
    'previously was affecting whatever sheet was active
    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")   'change name of sheet as required
        Application.Goto .Cells(1), 1

        ActiveWindow.View = xlPageBreakPreview 'moved out the loop just needed once
        ActiveSheet.ResetAllPageBreaks 'reset prior page breaks

        LR = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        Fname = .Cells(2, 5)

        For x = 3 To LR
            If .Cells(x, 5) <> Fname Then
                'no need to select the cell
                ActiveWindow.SelectedSheets.HPageBreaks.Add before:=.Cells(x, 1)
                Fname = .Cells(x, 5)
    End If: Next: End With

    'reset back the window view
    ActiveWindow.View = xlNormalView

End Sub
```

Comment: Thx EEM.  For some reason its still not working.  I've stepped through and it does everything apart from actually add the page breaks.  Any other thoughts?

Comment: is the macro in the workbook you want to be updated? I assume the worksheet nor the workbook are protected. I tested and it worked fine... Does it give any error? Could you post\share your workbook?

Comment: Hi EEM,  I played around some more... In the "Page Break Preview" view, there were dotted lines, once I moved these so that they turned solid, I re-run the macro and it worked perfectly.  So, not sure how to fix this with code, as you did include: "ActiveSheet.ResetAllPageBreaks".

Comment: HI @SimonA1 That is odd, the instruction should have delete all them. Could you please share the original with the doted lines I would like to see what's happening with them and why there were nor deleted.

Answer (score 0):

I'd have tried this (I'd select the entire row not just the cell):

```
Sub addpagebreaksatvalue()
    Dim x As Integer
    Dim LR As Integer
    Dim Fname As String
    Dim HPBreak As HPageBreak

    LR = Cells(rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    Fname = Cells(2, 5)

        For x = 3 To LR
            If Cells(x, 5) <> Fname Then
               ActiveWindow.View = xlPageBreakPreview
               For Each HPBreak In ActiveSheet.HPageBreaks
                   If HPBreak.Location.Row = x Then Exit For
                      Cells(x,1).EntireRow.Select                       
                      ActiveWindow.SelectedSheets.HPageBreaks.Add Before:=ActiveCell
               Next
               Fname = Cells(x, 5)
               Else: Fname = Cells(x, 5)
            End If
        Next

    ActiveWindow.View = xlNormalView

End Sub
```